# How to preview PHP files for Github?

Tags: php

I know there is [`HTMLPREVIEW.GITHUB.IO`](http://HTMLPREVIEW.GITHUB.IO)
 for html files, to see the output preview of file in line. Is something similar possible for `php` files?

Comment: This is not question. You can use google to look around or post in php-related forum.

Answer (score -1):

Github has a feature to publish projects as static site (only `html`,`js` files are executed ),like:

```
username.github.io
```

To preview/execute other extensions (like `php`,`c#`,`ruby`,`vb` etc...), you might use sites like:

- [**RunFor**github.com](http://RunForgithub.com)
- https://repl.it
- [www.writephponline.com](http://www.writephponline.com)
- etc..